# Unable to open Google Play store with Xamarin.Forms Portable class Library

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I use this to try and open the Google Play Store directly to my app however this does not work.

```
  var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName));
```

Comment: Whats the actual error, does anything open, is it not going to the correct product?

Comment: It is going to my product but not asking for update, it asking for Open only. actually I have to implement the above code in Xamarin.Forms PCL but I don't have any idea to implement it using viewmodel or PCL

Comment: That means the app hasn't been updated and it has the latest version. The App store will show Update if there is an update available, there is nothing you can do on your end to modify or change that.

Comment: ok. thanks and Can any one suggest me the related code for get latest version code from play store programatically in Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0):

In a Forms PCL project, you can open a URI by using [Device.OpenUri()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.OpenUri/p/System.Uri/)

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```